# Clicking/Ticking BEHIND Gas Stove

Tags: gas, stove

I recently noticed a continuous clicking/ticking noise behind my gas stove. If you stand in front of the stove and focus, you can hear it. To hear it really well, you have to lean in towards the stove. Definitely not metal expanding/contracting.  I don't smell any gas.  However, I don't think this is normal.  Also, it is not the clock.  Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: That might be the case if it was intermittent. LHS, please describe the sound more thoroughly in your question. How loud? How regular? Truly continuous (24/7)? If not, is it associated with stove usage, HVAC cycles, etc? Does the stove have a mechanical clock?

Comment: It is a continuous subtle ticking/clicking that's coming from behind the stove.  If you stand in front of the stove and focus, you can hear it.  To hear it really well, you have to lean in towards the stove.  Definitely not metal expanding/contracting.

Comment: Please revise your question to include the new information. It's not conspicuous down here. Be sure to address all my questions.

Comment: Looks like you've created two accounts, [this one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/97178/lhs) and [another one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/97204/lhs). Please use the Stack Exchange contact page to request that they be merged.

Comment: Not sure how that happened, but requested merge.  Also, I'd like to delete the question. Decided to unplug the stove to see if it would stop.  It did.  @isherwood was closest because the sound was coming from near the clock housing.  Go figure...  Thank you all for your suggestions to help pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to unplug the stove to see if it would stop. It did. @isherwood was closest with his suggestion because the sound was coming from near the clock housing where all the mechanical components are located. Go figure... Thank you all for your suggestions to help pinpoint the issue.